# Is this the correct formula for dopamine?

Tags: structural-formula

Google says that $C8H11NO2$ is the correct formula for dopamine. Is this so?

Comment: Without meaning to be rude, you could work this out, given that you know how to use google. Search for the molecular structure. To help you along, the CAS number for dopamine is 51-61-6.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to suspect that google is wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivial to answer with a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Take a look at the structure, you can easily work it out for such a small molecule.

Lets start with the really obvious ones:

Oxygens: 2
Nitrogens: 1

You then have to recognise that in a skeletal formula, the carbons are simply represented by 'corners' (i.e. where two lines meet):

Carbons: 8

Finally, you need to work out how many hydrogens are present. Hydrogens attached to heteroatoms (Oxygen and nitrogen) are shown, hydrogens attached to carbon are not, and hence you have to rely on your chemistry knowledge to work out how many should be attached to each carbon:

Hydrogens: 11

In short, yes, the formula is right for dopamine.